# Как поместить текст в одну строку с иконкой, но справа от нее?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Скрин экрана]

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}

nav {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #212121;
}


.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 13px 70px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu .menu_link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.menu .menu_item {
    border-right: 2px dotted black;
    padding-right: 28px;

}

.subheader {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 84px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);

    

}

.subheader .subheader_logo {
    display: block; /*если margin top не работает вероятно поставить display block*/
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.subheader .subheader_official {
    margin-top: 6px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.subheader .subheader_call {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: right;
}

.subheader .subheader_phone {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: right;
}

.subheader .subheader_btn {
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 172px;
    height: 46px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.promo {
    min-height: 800px;
    background: url('../../img/bg/main_bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
    padding: 190px 0 135px 0;

}

.promo .promo_header {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.promo .promo_subheader {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

.promo .promo_descr {
    color: #ffffff;;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 23px;
}

.promo .promo_btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 118px auto 0 auto; 
    width: 259px;
    height: 63px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.reasons {
    height: 900px;
}

.reasons .black_block {
    margin: 72px 916px 39px 500px;
}

.reasons .black {
    width: 112px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.reasons .adv {
    padding: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.reasons .work {
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}




.reasons .round_1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 113px;
    height: 113px;
    background-color: #1eacc7;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.reasons .wallet {
    width: 80px;
    height: 66px;

}

.reasons .reason_title {
    max-width: 340px;
    color: #1eacc7;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.reasons .reason_descr {
    max-width: 340px;
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.reasons .text_block_1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="subheader">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                <a href="#" class="subheader_logo"><img src="/icons/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                    <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
                    <a href="tel:84957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
                 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
           </div>
    </div>
    </header>

    <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
                <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
                <div class="promo_descr">Компания UBER  динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место среди
                    таксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы по заказам, компания начисляет бонусы за
                    пиковое время.
                    <br><br>
                    Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве.  Водители у нас
                    зарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.</div>
                    <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="reasons">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="black_block"><div class="adv">
            <div class="black">
                <div class="adv">преимущества</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work">8 причин начать работать с нами</div>
    <div class="round_1"> <img src="/icons/reasons/wallet.png" alt="wallet" class="wallet"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="text_block_1"><div class="reason_title">Никаких наличных, оплата происходит автоматически</div>
                <div class="reason_descr">
                  Стоимость поездки оплачивается пассажиром с привязанной банковской карты, т.е. нет никаких рисков связанных с перевозкой наличности как для пассажира, так и для водителя, Вам не нужно искать мелкие деньги для размена.</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (текст из .text_block_1, иконка в round_1)

Comment: Пробуйте через `display:flex`, но не уверен что сработает.

Comment: Иконку и текст в один блок оберните и присвойте этому блоку display: flex, или назначьте класс d-flex

Comment: Причём тут текст, если на сайте bootstrap разметка?

Comment: Сорри, имел в виду "при чём тут флекс", конечно же.

Comment: Я с bootstrap не очень знаком.

Comment: @xydope зачем флексы, если там сетка бутстраповская?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На будущее, можно было бы указать в качестве примера кода не всю html-страницу, а только проблемный участок, так проще будет искать проблему. Опять же, если уж есть бутстрап, можно иконку и текст разместить в разные колонки:

```
<div class="work">8 причин начать работать с нами</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><div class="round_1"> <img src="/icons/reasons/wallet.png" alt="wallet" class="wallet"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text_block_1">
                <div class="reason_title">Никаких наличных, оплата происходит автоматически</div>
                <div class="reason_descr">
                    Стоимость поездки оплачивается пассажиром с привязанной банковской карты, т.е. нет никаких рисков связанных с перевозкой наличности как для пассажира, так и для водителя, Вам не нужно искать мелкие деньги для размена.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. Класс .row всегда должен быть внутри .container
2. При помощи .col-md-1 и .col-md-5 описаны 1 колонка на иконку и 5 - на текст, всего это 6 колонок - то есть ровно половина из 12 бутстраповских колонок. Возможно вам в этой строке понадобится ещё такие же .col-md-1 и .col-md-5 для второго такого же элемента.
3. Можно перераспределить колонки не по 1 и 5, а, скажем, по 2 и 4, тогда надо будет использовать классы .col-md-2 и .col-md-4.
4. У вас прописано КАК будут распределяться колонки только для среднего разрешения экрана - md относится к диапазону от 992 пикселя и до 1200, если не путаю по памяти. А как колонки должны у вас распределяться для маленьких и больших разрешений?
5. Плохая практика совать заголовки по-сути в блоки див: "8 причин начать работать с нами" и "Никаких наличных, оплата происходит автоматически". Дивы, конечно могут оставаться, но правильнее с точки зрения seo и семантики кода было бы поместить их в заголовки, что-нибудь типа h2 и h3.

Comment: Спасибо больше, все учту!